# How could I make the MongoDB scalable with AWS ELB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

Currently, I can dynamically increase or decrease the APP servers with AWS ELB(just by monitoring the CPU loading).

However, All of the data is stored in MongoDB at one machine with 2GB Ram, all of the data is keeping updating as well,
It could NOT be easily scaled under burst incoming flow.
Vertical horizontal won't work because the server will be out of service for few minutes.
To create a new DB machine sounds won't work too. Because the newly created machine doesn't have updated data.

How could I design the DB infrastructure to handle this dynamic loading situation?

Most of the time, there are only about 20 members on my site. Nevertheless, at some particular moment, there will be about 1500 members on my site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the topic of replica sets to enable vertical scaling, and sharded deployments to enable horizontal scaling.
These topics are introduced nicely on page 10 of the following document - 
https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_NoSQL_MongoDB.pdf

Both these features are slightly complex and will take some intimate knowledge with mongo to work well. If you want an out-of-the-box solution, you can run you DB on a seperate service outside AWS. We are using compose.io for this matter. It satisfies our needs during peak hours and isn't that expensive.